# Desencriptar password con php, codeigniter y phpmyhadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, codeigniter

Tengo una sistema de membresias al cual los socios son cargados al sistema por terceros, al momento de ingresar los datos de los usuarios la clave es una clave standar y esta se emcripta al ser almacenada en la base de datos con los metodos MD5,SHA1 quedan la linea de encriptacion  de la sigiente manera

```
'clave' => MD5(SHA1($this->input->post('clave', true)))
```

al momento de enviarle el correo al usuario de su afiliacion al sistema el mismo envia la clave pero encriptada, lo que necesito saber es si es posible esa clave encriptada volverla a su forma original para que el cliente pueda accesar y despues realizar el cambio de la misma.

Trabajo con el framework codeigniter 3 y la base de datos esta en PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Lo estás planteando mal, si tu sistema permite obtener de vuelta el string original de la contraseña entonces tiene un problema de seguridad muy grave

Comment: no actualmente el sistema devuelve la clave encriptada, lo que necesito es, de ser posible, me regrese la clave original, para que el cliente puedo iniciar sesion y luego cambiarla

Comment: Las funciones que usan algoritmos de encriptación, si son mediamente seguras, son solamente en un solo sentido: se puede codificar algo pero no decodificarlo para obtener lo que se codificó inicialmente.

Comment: Además estás usando SHA1 cuando la propia doc. indica que no debería ser usado para contraseñas: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sha1.php y lo mismo con md5 https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, sera aplicar una clave temporal para este caso

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar la funcion de php **password_hash** para cifrar la contraseña y luego añades la contraseña ya cifrada desde php a la base de datos, ejemplo:

```
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];

$contraseña_cifrada = password_hash($contraseña, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>3]);
```

El ultimo parametro de **password_hash** (['cost'=>3) son las veces que va a cifrar la contraseña, la cifra una vez y luego otra hasta cifrarla las veces que se le haya indicado. Y ya para decifrarla solo haces esto: `password_verify($contraseña_cifrada, $contraseña);`
El primer parametro es la contraseña cifrada y el segundo es la contraseña normal, si es la correcta duvuelve **true** y si no devuelve **false**.

Comment: `password_verify` no decifra nada,  checa aqui: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Me explique mal, podiran comprobar que si  el resultado es **true** imprimen la contraseña normal, no se si me explique bien

Answer (score 1):

Hola buenas tardes queria pedir ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
que hago porque no puedo entrar ahy

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349386)

Comment: Eso no parece una respuesta, considera eliminarla y redáctala como una nueva pregunta.